# Slow firestore runTransaction call - executing slow

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

```
const giveAnswer = async(user,lobby,questionNumber,answer)=>{
    const lobbyRef = doc(db, "lobbies", lobby.id);
    const newAnswer ={
      user:user.id,
      answer:answer, 
    }
    
  await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
    const lobbySnapshot = await transaction.get(lobbyRef);
    const oldArray = lobbySnapshot.data().answers;
    const currentQuestion = oldArray.find(obj => obj.questionNumber === questionNumber);
  
    if (currentQuestion) {
      currentQuestion.responses.push(newAnswer);
    }
    else{
      const Theme = {
        questionNumber: questionNumber,
        responses: [newAnswer],
      }  
      oldArray.push(Theme);
    }
  
    transaction.update(lobbyRef, { answers: oldArray });
  });
}
```

I am working on a react project where users can solve tests online with each others. I am using Firestore for database.

When users try to answer this function working. But executing progress taking higher than 1-2 sec. how can i improve that?

Comment: Depending on your network connection, 1-2 seconds may actually be quite reasonable for first reading a document and then writing it. What makes you say this can be faster?

Comment: Before runTransaction, I was using updateDoc and it was much faster, but I switched to runTransaction because errors occurred when many people responded at the same time. I'm wondering if I can get the speed with runTransaction that I get with updateDoc.

Comment: `updateDoc` doesn't have to first read the document, so it makes sense that that is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a transaction you want to first read the document and then write its new value based on its current value. That will always be slower than calling `updateDoc` *without* first reading the document, as the read takes time too.

If you want the performance to improve, look for a data model that doesn't require you to first read the document - for example with an [`arrayUnion()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).